# Dynamically append new links to top of list instead of bottom of list

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am dynamically adding links to my list. The newest links are added to the bottom of the list. How would one append each new link to the top of the list?

```
<ul class="posts" id="posts">
  <% for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++) { %>
    <li class="post">
      <span><a href="/collab/<%=posts[i]['_id']%>"><%= posts[i].userCreate %></a></span>
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly you need to iterate your list from the end to the front:

```
for (var i = posts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Comment: I should have thought of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the `posts` array in a reverse way. see:

```js
for (var i = posts.length; i > -1; i--) {
  // echo <li> element
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your correct answer. ManosM posted the correct answer first so I gave him the answer, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

just reverse your for loop from post.length to 0.

```
for(var i=posts.length-1; i>=0; i--){}
```